# gLightbox Custom Description not working properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I'm using [gLightbox](https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/) on my site. I am using the `description: custom-desc;` feature to make the description. The link works great when on desktop. However, as soon as I switch to a mobile device the link doesn't work. It's just showing up with the text.

```js
const glightbox = GLightbox({
  selector: '.glightbox'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/css/glightbox.css" integrity="sha512-iQ3H4A+iyBTP8M4ypX5PrTt2S+G1zmRjf0k0uOASKlFHysV8TL9ZoQyVwPss0D12IBTMoDEHA8+bg8a1viS9Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-present">
  <div class="portfolio-info">
    <h4>heading</h4>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" title="Quick View" data-gallery="portfolio-gallery" class="glightbox preview-link" data-glightbox="title: title; description: .custom-desc16;"><i class="bi bi-zoom-in"></i>
      <div class="glightbox-desc custom-desc16">
        <a href="https://google.com" title="Full Property" class="full-property-link">Link that doesn't work<i class="bi bi-link-45deg"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Portfolio Item -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/js/glightbox.min.js" integrity="sha512-S/H9RQ6govCzeA7F9D0m8NGfsGf0/HjJEiLEfWGaMCjFzavo+DkRbYtZLSO+X6cZsIKQ6JvV/7Y9YMaYnSGnAA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/js/glightbox.js" integrity="sha512-B15xrHLAFUGC5w4jO8iQtCLLaliORCeLUCewc3Pjrtzw6y2ZXECO6bHalENItF5p/yPpz02fGL/luT/Bs17WnA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

It shows up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGlV.png) on mobile while in my dev tools. It's completely removing the `a href` altogether.

I can provide link to dev site if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `moreLength:0`. gLightbox's default `moreLength` is `60`.

For full explanation, please see [here](https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox/issues/299).

For example on how to set it, see [here](https://codepen.io/gingerchew/pen/gOxQJwM/1a9fa39380883be7bb70145d8f5bdad5).

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Is there any side effect from using this on desktop also? What exactly does `moreLength: 0` or `moreLength: 60` mean?

Comment: It means that if the slide description is more than 60 characters, it will add the "see more" link.

Comment: Changing the 'moreLength' won't affect the desktop. But if your descriptions are too long, it won't generate the "see more" link and may affect your layout.